# Integration by substitution in reverse

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

While browsing through some notes on integral substitution i found a neat little problem that i would like very much to check my understanding of with you.
I am to suggest an integral that is reduced to a rational function integral when this substitution is used:

$a)$ $t=\sin x$

$b)$ $t=\sqrt[6] {x+5}$

$c$ $\sqrt{1-9x^2}=-1+xt$

I found this to be a very interesting problem and wanted to check my results with you. For the first part  i think that
a) $\int \sin x\cos x \, dx$ is a good idea couse when we introduce the given substitution we are left with $\int t \, dt$ which is a rational function, right?
For the second part i have some struggles but i think that
b) $\int \frac{\sqrt[6] {(x+5)^5}}{6\sqrt[6] {x+5}} \, dx$ would reduce to $\int t \, dt$
As for the part c) that i the second Euler substitution and the integral that is suited for it should be any integral of the form c) $\int \sqrt {ax^2+bx+1} \, dx$ where $a,b$ can be any number. Care to share your thoughts on this? Perhaps some suggestions of your own or corrections on mine?

Thanks, :)